# Facebook meta image not working on sharing

Tags: html, image, facebook, http, meta

Custom Facebook image on share button doesn't appear. I am trying from localhost, can it be a reason?(can't test in production yet). Image address is taken from web, tried different

```
<meta property="og:type"          content="here is production website address" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="https://crunchbase-production-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/c_limit,h_600,w_600/v1422480063/h0fvargheeyaybm4oyyt.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

The button. Links are to real website pages, but meta tags is the only thing that matters in representation on Facebook side(as I know)

```
<div class="fb-share-button"  style="width: 250px;
  height: 56px;
  background-color: #3a5998; text-align: center;line-height: 54px;color:white;" data-href="http://www.tick-tock.com.ua/event/144/" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.tick-tock.com.ua/event/135/" style="color: white;">Share on Facebook</a></div>
```

What else can make it not work? Didn't find any direct answer, not so many duplicate answers to similar.

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work on your localhost. Facebook actually scrapes a page reading the og meta information. It can't scrape your localhost.

However, once you get it online, you can have the Facebook OG debugger scrape the page right away and read the meta data.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1):

Facebook sharer no longer support custom fields like picture, name, caption, thumbnail, description.

For more information check: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog and look for 'Deprecations in v2.9'